# Prestashop docker

Tags: docker, github, prestashop

I am trying to install prestashop from github on docker. I don’t want to install an image of the prestashop because I understood that if I make changes on that I can’t upload them on a real server because there isn’t a file in the computer. I tryed to install the version from github and when I try to enter the webpage it shows me local host didn’t send any data.

Comment: If you are facing basic issues with using a unchanged Docker image, you should better ask the maintainer of that Docker image for help

Comment: Do you still have the error? I've found that sometimes you need to wait a few seconds to give it time to boot the web server, if you look at the container log you'll see this:"* Setting up install lock file...
* Reapplying PrestaShop files for enabled volumes ...
* No pre-install script found, let's continue...
* No post-install script found, let's continue...
* Setup completed, removing lock file...
* Almost ! Starting web server now
* No init script found, let's continue..." and then it should be working. btw you should use the base version instead of git and bind mount ps code into it